# Why is adaptive execution disabled and undocumented in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have recently discovered [adaptive execution](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/internal/SQLConf.scala#L310).

None of the `spark.sql.adaptive.*` parameters seem to be present in the Spark SQL documentation, and the flag is disabled by default.

This seems like an interesting feature, which appears to have been there since Spark 2.0.

How come this isn't in the official documentation and/or activated by default?  Are there known pitfalls to using adaptive execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spark.sql.adaptive` doesn't do much in spark 2.x from end use perspective, there were efforts for alternative approach from contributors to make it more aware and efficient. The outcome of this effort should be a prime candidate for spark 3.x apart from AI improvements. see this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23128